# Hashi Corp Vault Error : "check unable to talk with Consul backend"

Tags: docker-compose, consul, hashicorp-vault

I have a 3 node consul cluster running on docker with the following config :

```
{
  "bootstrap_expect": 3,
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "domain": "consul",
  "enable_script_checks": true,
  "dns_config": {
    "enable_truncate": true,
    "only_passing": true
  },
  "enable_syslog": false,
  "encrypt": "myfinetoken==",
  "leave_on_terminate": true,
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "rejoin_after_leave": true,
  "server": true,
  "ui": true,
  "connect": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "start_join": [
    "consul-server-1",
    "consul-server-2",
    "consul-server-3"
  ]
}
```

in addition I have a consul-client to talk to vault with the following config

```
{
  "server": false,
  "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "encrypt": "myfinetoken==",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "enable_script_checks": true,
  "enable_syslog": false,
  "leave_on_terminate": true,
  "connect": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "retry_join": [
    "consul-server-1",
    "consul-server-2",
    "consul-server-3"
  ]
}
```

This is accomplished by a vault container with the following

```
  "storage": {
    "consul": {
      "address": "consul-client-1:8500",
      "path": "vault/"
    }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

The consul cluster runs fine. Even with the joined client. I can use the gui, the api ... no problem but when I start the vault-server (one node with one corresponding consul-client) I reveive the following error in Vault :

```
2022-09-12T10:37:41.303Z [WARN]  service_registration.consul: reconcile unable to talk with Consul backend: error="service registration failed: Unexpected response code: 400 (Invalid service address)"
2022-09-12T10:37:42.160862000Z 2022-09-12T10:37:42.160Z [WARN]  service_registration.consul: check unable to talk with Consul backend: error="Unexpected response code: 404 (Unknown check ID \"vault:0.0.0.0:8200:vault-sealed-check\". Ensure that the check ID is passed, not the check name.)"
```

The consule client says :

```
2022-09-12T10:42:49.231Z [ERROR] agent.http: Request error: method=PUT url=/v1/agent/check/fail/vault:0.0.0.0:8200:vault-sealed-check?note=Vault+Sealed from=172.27.0.7:49160 error="Unknown check ID "vault:0.0.0.0:8200:vault-sealed-check". Ensure that the check ID is passed, not the check name."
2022-09-12T10:42:50.236301300Z 2022-09-12T10:42:50.235Z [ERROR] agent.http: Request error: method=PUT url=/v1/agent/check/fail/vault:0.0.0.0:8200:vault-sealed-check?note=Vault+Sealed from=172.27.0.7:49160 error="Unknown check ID "vault:0.0.0.0:8200:vault-sealed-check". Ensure that the check ID is passed, not the check name."
```

Any help kindly appreciated

Comment: Can you use the Raft storage backend instead?

Comment: @MattSchuchard see answer below. Yes this is working

Comment: As of Vault version 1.4 I would recommend using the Raft storage backend without a compelling reason otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raft backend is working so far I am using the following docker-compose :

```
vault-server-1:
    build:
      context: ./vault
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
      - "8201:8201"
    command: server -config=/vault/config/vault-config-server-1.hcl
    environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: "http://vault-server-1:8200"
      VAULT_API_ADDR: "https://vault-server-1:8201"
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - raft-data:/var/raftdata
    depends_on:
      - consul-client-1
```

Beside the vault-config:

```
storage "raft" {
  path = "/var/raftdata"
  node_id = "raft_node_1"
}

cluster_addr = "http://vault-server-1:8200"
```

The docker image is build with :

```
# base image
FROM vault:1.11.3

RUN apk add curl

RUN mkdir -p /var/raftdata
RUN chmod o+w /var/raftdata

COPY ./config/vault-config.json /vault/config/vault-config.json
COPY ./config/vault-config-server-1.hcl /vault/config/vault-config-server-1.hcl
```

Based on this Solution for a dockerized production Vault I now have a suitable Version see => https://github.com/ahmetkaftan/docker-vault

**Full setup**

dockerfile

```
FROM vault:1.11.9
LABEL maintainer="ebusiness-opsboard@acme.de"

ADD --chown=vault:vault config.hcl /vault/config/config.hcl
ADD --chown=vault:vault certs /vault/config/certs

# add Digicert root certificate, so alpine will be able to validate vaults certificate chain https://de.ssl-tools.net/subjects/253b2763b69868d3e868968efbcc68c6c444d411
ADD digicert_68f22b1a6298f7da191e6149ed8de0efff54ad8c.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

config.hcl

```
listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/vault/config/certs/cert.pem"
  tls_key_file  = "/vault/config/certs/key.pem"
}

storage "raft" {
  path = "/vault/file"
}

# basiert auf :   https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/monitoring/monitor-telemetry-grafana-prometheus

telemetry {
  disable_hostname = true
  prometheus_retention_time = "12h"
}

disable_mlock = "true"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  vault:
    image: docker.acme.de/acme/vault:1.11.9.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VAULT_RAFT_NODE_ID=${NODE_ID} # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration/storage/raft#node_id
      - VAULT_UI=true # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration#ui
      - VAULT_API_ADDR=https://${VAULT_DNS}:8200 # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration#api_addr
      - VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR=https://${VAULT_DNS}:8201 # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration#cluster_addr
      - VAULT_LOG_LEVEL=warn
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
      - 8201:8201
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/vault-${DEPLOYMENT_ENV}/file:/vault/file
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    command: vault server --config=/vault/config/config.hcl
    healthcheck:
      test: wget -qS https://${VAULT_DNS}:8200/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $$2}' | grep 200 # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/system/health#429
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
```

Comment: do you mind sharing your full setup? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update @mbieren, I thought you were running a HA with multiple replicas (or global), that’s what I’m trying to do, though I did implemented it with Consul, but the guys at Hashicorps tend to lean towards Raft. Thanks.

Comment: This dockerfile is applied to more than one host (4 in total) when creating the cluster the first one is the master (store the unsealkeys) and root token. New hosts are then joined to the cluster with => see my answer

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Initialize Vault in the first Vault container:

```
acmepdkr001 > docker exec -it vault_vault_1 sh

/ # export VAULT_ADDR=https://v01.vault.acme.de:8200
/ # vault operator init
```

Save unseal keys and the root token

**2.** Unseal first Vault container:

```
acmepdkr001 > docker exec -it vault_vault_1 sh

/ # vault operator unseal
/ # vault operator unseal
/ # vault operator unseal
```

**3.** Join every other Vault containers by executing following command on every container:

```
acmedkr001 > docker exec -it vault_vault_1 sh

/ # export VAULT_ADDR=https://v02.vault.acme.de:8200
/ # vault operator raft join https://v01.vault.acme.de:8200
```